# How to configure OpenBox to ignore the size hint of a specific application's window?

Tags: window-manager, size, rxvt, fullscreen

#### Updated Question

Based on the excellent comment by [@mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473183/urxvt-gapless-window-size#comment864255_473183) it is actually the window manager that is respecting or ignoring the propagated size hint of a window.  Unfortunately though, I couldn't find a way to either not send size hint from `urxvt` or ignore the sent one by `OpenBox`.

So I guess my question really is: Is there a way at the `urxvt` level to stop sending size hint?  Or is there a way to configure `OpenBox` to ignore the sent size hint for a specific application?

---

#### Original Question: 'urxvt gapless window size'

I'm using OpenBox as my window manager, and I have some hot keys configured to move windows into certain areas of the screen with a specified window size.  All windows are respecting this, except `urxvt` which is calculating its size based on the font size of the characters it is displaying.  However, if `urxvt` is in fullscreen mode<sup>†</sup>, it is capable of filling the screen without gaps.  *(I assume it is just using the configured X background and filling in the remaining space aroung the window — but I can be wrong about this.)*

So my question is this: is there a builtin configuration option or maybe a perl extension that makes `urxvt` fill all the space the window manager is giving it to without gaps when it is not in fullscreen mode?

---

<sup>†</sup>Probably worth mentioning, that I'm using [a perl extension](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/urxvt-fullscreen) already for a proper fullscreen experience.

Comment: Why the `-1` without any explanation?

Comment: Search for 'ignore size hints' either with rxvt or with your window manager. If you don't find anything acceptable, I'll try to make a LD_PRELOAD hack.

Comment: @mosvy thanks for the comment, I updated my question, as you can read so far no luck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix it is to modify either the source of `rxvt` or the source of `openbox` and to recompile -- look at the bottom of this answer for two **very simple** patches.

Another way is use an `LD_PRELOAD` hack that will turn off the `PResizeInc` flag when getting the `WM_NORMAL_HINTS` window property, and will prevent it from being turned on when setting that property. This will only affect the `width_inc` and `height_inc` properties -- programs that set their minimum window size or its aspect ratio will continue to work fine.

```
$ cat no_inc_size_hints.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

Status XGetWMNormalHints(Display *dpy, Window w, XSizeHints *hp, long *rp){
    static typeof (XGetWMNormalHints) *orig;
    Status r;
    if(!orig) orig = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "XGetWMNormalHints");
    if((r = orig(dpy, w, hp, rp)))
        hp->flags &= ~PResizeInc;
    return r;
}
void XSetWMNormalHints(Display *dpy, Window w, XSizeHints *hp){
    static typeof (XSetWMNormalHints) *orig;
    if(!orig) orig = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "XSetWMNormalHints");
    hp->flags &= ~PResizeInc;
    orig(dpy, w, hp);
}
$ cc -shared -fPIC -Wall no_inc_size_hints.c -ldl -o no_inc_size_hints.so
```

Then `urxvt` or `openbox` will have to be run with the

```
LD_PRELOAD="$LD_PRELOAD /absolute/path/to/no_inc_size_hints.so"
```

variable in their environment. Example:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/no_inc_size_hints.so openbox --replace
```

There are two problems with this:

1) `urxvt` is usually installed as a utmp setgid binary, and the `LD_PRELOAD` variable is cleared when exec'ing a set[gu]id binary. Look in the man page for why the utmp permission is (not) needed.
So you'll have to copy the `urxvt` executable elsewhere (which will turn the setgid bit off). Example:

```
$ cp `which urxvt` .; LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/no_inc_size_hints.so ./urxvt
```

2) The window manager is usually called through `ssh-agent` from the `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` scripts on many systems, and `ssh-agent`
will also wipe the `LD_PRELOAD` variable from the environment. So something like this may be needed:

```
# cat <<'EOT' >/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98-no_inc_size_hints
export LD_PRELOAD="$LD_PRELOAD /path/to/no_inc_size_hints.so"
case $STARTUP in
/usr/bin/ssh-agent*)
        STARTUP="/usr/bin/ssh-agent env LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD ${STARTUP#* }";;
esac
EOT
```

Possible patch for `openbox-3.6.1`:

```
--- openbox/client.c~   2018-10-06 08:34:25.615967414 +0300
+++ openbox/client.c    2018-10-06 08:34:28.916133702 +0300
@@ -1757,9 +1757,6 @@ void client_update_normal_hints(ObClient
         if (size.flags & PBaseSize)
             SIZE_SET(self->base_size, size.base_width, size.base_height);

-        if (size.flags & PResizeInc && size.width_inc && size.height_inc)
-            SIZE_SET(self->size_inc, size.width_inc, size.height_inc);
-
         ob_debug("Normal hints: min size (%d %d) max size (%d %d)",
                  self->min_size.width, self->min_size.height,
                  self->max_size.width, self->max_size.height);
```

and for `rxvt-unicode-9.22`:

```
--- src/main.C~ 2018-10-06 08:33:08.580085731 +0300
+++ src/main.C  2018-10-06 08:33:37.549545455 +0300
@@ -657,7 +657,7 @@ rxvt_term::window_calc (unsigned int new
   unsigned int w, h;
   unsigned int max_width, max_height;

-  szHint.flags = PMinSize | PResizeInc | PBaseSize | PWinGravity;
+  szHint.flags = PMinSize | PBaseSize | PWinGravity;
   szHint.win_gravity = NorthWestGravity;
   /* szHint.min_aspect.x = szHint.min_aspect.y = 1; */

@@ -1073,7 +1073,7 @@ rxvt_term::resize_all_windows (unsigned
     {
       szHint.flags &= ~(PBaseSize | PResizeInc);
       XSetWMNormalHints (dpy, parent, &szHint);
-      szHint.flags |= PBaseSize | PResizeInc;
+      szHint.flags |= PBaseSize;
     }

   if (!ignoreparent)
```

Both are against the versions from debian 9.5; they'll only apply with `patch -l` -- I don't know how to get this damn thing to preserve tabs.

Comment: You are a genius, mate, no doubt!  Thanks for the explanations and possible solutions/suggestions.  I think at this point it is fare to say that the best option would be to contact the developers of each of these projects, show them your answer and make them aware that this is indeed a thing that is needed and one which unfortunately has no obvious workaround therefore they should introduce configurable options about it.  But this probably is not your concern anymore :)  Cheers again!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. However I cannot make work your fix/patch on the Openbox sources. Do you know of an obvious reason why the resize hints would still be applied with your patch? An idea I could investigate? I am using Ubuntu 1804. Thanks!

Comment: @njames No idea. What terminal are you using? Also, did you build from the original sources, or from the debian package with `dpkg-source -b`?

Comment: @mosvy I use mate-terminal, but I tested with rxvt too and cannot make it work. I compiled the source v3.6.1 from the Openbox website.